# The perfect way to validate and test Rails 3 associations (using RSpec/Remarkable)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm still pretty new to testing in Rails 3, and I use RSpec and Remarkable. I read through a lot of posts and some books already, but I'm still kind of stuck in uncertainty when to use the association's name, when its ID.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Because of good practice, I want to protect my attributes from mass assignments:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :project  # Or is it :project_id??

  belongs_to :project
end
```

First of all, I want to make sure that a project **never** exists without a valid task:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :project, :presence => true      # Which one is the...
  validates :project_id, :presence => true   # ...right way to go??
end
```

I also want to make sure that the assigned project or project ID is always valid:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :project, :associated => true     # Again, which one is...
  validates :project_id, :associated => true  # ...the right way to go?
end
```

...and do I need the validation on :presence when I use :associated??

Thanks a lot for clarifying, it seems that after hours of reading and trying to test stuff using RSpec/Shoulda/Remarkable I don't see the forest because of all the trees anymore...

Comment: Nice clear question. To confirm, don't you mean you want to "make sure that a task **never** exists without a valid (parent) project"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This seems to be the right way to do it:

```
attr_accessible :project_id
```

You don't have to put `:project` there, too! It's anyway possible to do `task.project=(Project.first!)`

Then check for the existence of the `:project_id` using the following (`:project_id` is also set when `task.project=(...)` is used):

```
validates :project_id, :presence => true
```

Now make sure than an associated Project is valid like this:

```
validates :project, :associated => true
```

So:

```
t = Task.new
t.project_id = 1 # Value is accepted, regardless whether there is a Project with ID 1
t.project = Project.first # Any existing valid project is accepted
t.project = Project.new(:name => 'valid value') # A new valid project is accepted
t.project = Project.new(:name => 'invalid value') # A new invalid (or an existing invalid) project is NOT accepted!
```

It's a bit a pity that when assigning an ID through `t.project_id =` it's not checked whether this specific ID really exists. You have to check this using a custom validation or using the [Validates Existence GEM](https://github.com/perfectline/validates_existence).

To test these associations using RSpec with Remarkable matchers, do something like:

```
describe Task do
  it { should validate_presence_of :project_id }
  it { should validate_associated :project }
end
```

Comment: Wow this is an eye-opener. And I'm getting unexpected results with Rails 3.2.3. Try this. In the Task model, add `validates :project, :presence => true` but no `:associated` validation. In the console, create a new task with project_id=999 and check if it is `.valid?`. Rails looks for the record in the projects table, then (presumably because it's not found and project_id is still nil), the validation fails. Now change the validation to `validates :project_id, :presence => true`. Rails does NOT read projects and the validation succeeds. Add `:associated` and the validation *still* succeeds.

Answer (score 4):

```
validates :project, :associated => true  
validates :project_id, :presence => true
```

> If you want to be sure that an association is present, you’ll need to
>   test whether the foreign key used to map the association is present,
>   and not the associated object itself.
>   http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html

```
attr_accessible :project_id
```

Comment: That's a direct quote from the documentation, but in my testing with Rails 3.2.3, it works exactly the opposite. If you validate presence on the association (`:project, :presence => true`), it fails validation if the project_id doesn't exist in the projects table. But if you validate presence on the id (`:project_id, :presence => true`), `.valid?` returns `true` no matter what value you assign to project_id. Adding `validates :project, :associated => true` doesn't help--it still accepts non-existent project_ids. Pretty confused about how one is supposed to validate associations!

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: assuming that the association is not optional...

The only way I can get it to thoroughly validate is this:

```
validates_associated :project
validates_presence_of :project_id, 
    :unless => Proc.new {|o| o.project.try(:new_record?)}
validates_presence_of :project, :if => Proc.new {|o| o.project_id}
```

The first line validates whether the associated Project is valid, if there is one. The second line insists on the `project_id` being present, unless the associated Project exists and is new (if it's a new record, it won't have an ID yet). The third line ensures that the Project is present if there is an ID present, i.e., if the associated Project has already been saved.

ActiveRecord will assign a `project_id` to the task if you assign a saved Project to `project`. If you assign an unsaved/new Project to `project`, it will leave `project_id` blank. Thus, we want to ensure that `project_id` is present, but only when dealing with a saved Project; this is accomplished in line two above.

Conversely, if you assign a number to `project_id` that represents a real Project, ActiveRecord will fill in `project` with the corresponding Project object. But if the ID you assigned is bogus, it will leave `project` as nil. Thus line three above, which ensures that we have a `project` if `project_id` is filled in -- if you supply a bogus ID, this will fail.

See RSpec examples that test these validations: https://gist.github.com/kianw/5085085

Answer (score 2):

Joshua Muheim's solution works, but I hate being not be able to simply link a project to a task with an id like this:

```
t = Task.new
t.project_id = 123 # Won't verify if it's valid or not.
```

So I came up with this instead:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord:Base

    belongs_to :project

    validates :project_id, :presence => true
    validate :project_exists

    private
    def project_exists
        # Validation will pass if the project exists
        valid = Project.exists?(self.project_id)
        self.errors.add(:project, "doesn't exist.") unless valid
    end

end
```