# "Contact has_many :addresses" does work when checking presence of :contact, within Address, but not with :contact_id (and without validation)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, belongs-to

I really had a hard time tracking this problem down, and now I know what's going wrong, but don't know why, and whether it's a bug or not.

```
macbuech:iq josh$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0]
macbuech:iq josh$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.1
```

I have a model `Contact` which `has_many :addresses`. Everything worked perfectly so far, until I decided to validate presence of `Address.contact_id`, which seems to break the `my_contact.addresses << my_address` functionality! First of all how it used to work:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contact
  validates :contact, :presence => true
  # ...
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses
  # ...
end
```

Here's the output of a test in the Rails console:

```
1.9.3p0 :001 > c = FactoryGirl.create :contact
 => #<Contact id: 71, corporate: false, companyname: nil, firstname: nil, middlename: nil, lastname: "Doe", initials: nil, nickname: nil, gender: "male", title: nil, profession: nil, department: nil, birthday: nil, spouse: nil, kids: nil, superior: nil, assistant: nil, contacttype_id: 71, language_id: nil> 
1.9.3p0 :002 > a = FactoryGirl.create :address
 => #<Address id: 63, active: true, standard: false, street: "Mustergasse 123", extraline1: nil, extraline2: nil, city: "Musterhausen", zip: 8088, province: nil, pobox: nil, latitude: nil, longitude: nil, validfrom: nil, validto: nil, label: nil, description: nil, contact_id: 72, addresstype_id: 63, country_id: 63> 
1.9.3p0 :003 > c.addresses
 => [] 
1.9.3p0 :004 > c.addresses << a
 => [#<Address id: 63, active: true, standard: false, street: "Mustergasse 123", extraline1: nil, extraline2: nil, city: "Musterhausen", zip: 8088, province: nil, pobox: nil, latitude: nil, longitude: nil, validfrom: nil, validto: nil, label: nil, description: nil, contact_id: 71, addresstype_id: 63, country_id: 63>] 
1.9.3p0 :005 > c.addresses
 => [#<Address id: 63, active: true, standard: false, street: "Mustergasse 123", extraline1: nil, extraline2: nil, city: "Musterhausen", zip: 8088, province: nil, pobox: nil, latitude: nil, longitude: nil, validfrom: nil, validto: nil, label: nil, description: nil, contact_id: 71, addresstype_id: 63, country_id: 63>] 
1.9.3p0 :006 > c.save!
 => true 
1.9.3p0 :007 > c.reload
1.9.3p0 :008 > c.addresses
 => [#<Address id: 63, active: true, standard: false, street: "Mustergasse 123", extraline1: nil, extraline2: nil, city: "Musterhausen", zip: "8088", province: nil, pobox: nil, latitude: nil, longitude: nil, validfrom: nil, validto: nil, label: nil, description: nil, contact_id: 71, addresstype_id: 63, country_id: 63>]
```

Everything works as expected, the Address#63 now belongs to Contact#71.

I then read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11327575/1439143) that it doesn't make much sense to validate the presence of the belongs_to relationship name, but that I should validate its foreign key, and so I did:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contact
  validates :contact_id, :presence => true
  # ...
end
```

So here's the Rails console's log for exactly the same commands like above:

```
1.9.3p0 :009 > c = FactoryGirl.create :contact
 => #<Contact id: 84, corporate: false, companyname: nil, firstname: nil, middlename: nil, lastname: "Doe", initials: nil, nickname: nil, gender: "male", title: nil, profession: nil, department: nil, birthday: nil, spouse: nil, kids: nil, superior: nil, assistant: nil, contacttype_id: 84, language_id: nil> 
1.9.3p0 :010 > a = FactoryGirl.create :address
 => #<Address id: 74, active: true, standard: false, street: "Mustergasse 123", extraline1: nil, extraline2: nil, city: "Musterhausen", zip: 8088, province: nil, pobox: nil, latitude: nil, longitude: nil, validfrom: nil, validto: nil, label: nil, description: nil, contact_id: 85, addresstype_id: 74, country_id: 74> 
1.9.3p0 :011 > c.addresses
 => [] 
1.9.3p0 :012 > c.addresses << a
 => [#<Address id: 74, active: true, standard: false, street: "Mustergasse 123", extraline1: nil, extraline2: nil, city: "Musterhausen", zip: 8088, province: nil, pobox: nil, latitude: nil, longitude: nil, validfrom: nil, validto: nil, label: nil, description: nil, contact_id: 85, addresstype_id: 74, country_id: 74>] 
1.9.3p0 :013 > c.addresses
 => [#<Address id: 74, active: true, standard: false, street: "Mustergasse 123", extraline1: nil, extraline2: nil, city: "Musterhausen", zip: 8088, province: nil, pobox: nil, latitude: nil, longitude: nil, validfrom: nil, validto: nil, label: nil, description: nil, contact_id: 85, addresstype_id: 74, country_id: 74>] 
 => true 
1.9.3p0 :015 > c.reload
 => #<Contact id: 84, corporate: false, companyname: nil, firstname: nil, middlename: nil, lastname: "Doe", initials: nil, nickname: nil, gender: "male", title: nil, profession: nil, department: nil, birthday: nil, spouse: nil, kids: nil, superior: nil, assistant: nil, contacttype_id: 84, language_id: nil> 
1.9.3p0 :016 > c.addresses
 => []
```

As you can see, the address wasn't properly assigned to the contact! Its `:contact_id` stayed 85 although it should have changed after `c.addresses << a`! Even scarier, when I remove the whole validation, it **also** doesn't work!

```
1.9.3p0 :009 > c = FactoryGirl.create :contact
 => #<Contact id: 97, corporate: false, companyname: nil, firstname: nil, middlename: nil, lastname: "Doe", initials: nil, nickname: nil, gender: "male", title: nil, profession: nil, department: nil, birthday: nil, spouse: nil, kids: nil, superior: nil, assistant: nil, contacttype_id: 97, language_id: nil> 
1.9.3p0 :010 > a = FactoryGirl.create :address
 => #<Address id: 85, active: true, standard: false, street: "Mustergasse 123", extraline1: nil, extraline2: nil, city: "Musterhausen", zip: 8088, province: nil, pobox: nil, latitude: nil, longitude: nil, validfrom: nil, validto: nil, label: nil, description: nil, contact_id: 98, addresstype_id: 85, country_id: 85> 
1.9.3p0 :011 > c.addresses
 => [] 
1.9.3p0 :012 > c.addresses << a
 => [#<Address id: 85, active: true, standard: false, street: "Mustergasse 123", extraline1: nil, extraline2: nil, city: "Musterhausen", zip: 8088, province: nil, pobox: nil, latitude: nil, longitude: nil, validfrom: nil, validto: nil, label: nil, description: nil, contact_id: 98, addresstype_id: 85, country_id: 85>] 
1.9.3p0 :013 > c.addresses
 => [#<Address id: 85, active: true, standard: false, street: "Mustergasse 123", extraline1: nil, extraline2: nil, city: "Musterhausen", zip: 8088, province: nil, pobox: nil, latitude: nil, longitude: nil, validfrom: nil, validto: nil, label: nil, description: nil, contact_id: 98, addresstype_id: 85, country_id: 85>] 
1.9.3p0 :014 > c.save!
 => true 
1.9.3p0 :015 > c.reload
 => #<Contact id: 97, corporate: false, companyname: nil, firstname: nil, middlename: nil, lastname: "Doe", initials: nil, nickname: nil, gender: "male", title: nil, profession: nil, department: nil, birthday: nil, spouse: nil, kids: nil, superior: nil, assistant: nil, contacttype_id: 97, language_id: nil> 
1.9.3p0 :016 > c.addresses
 => []
```

Again, the very same scenario that the `:contact_id` does not change...

Any help is highly appreciated, I've wasted about 6 hours already investigating this problem...

**Update**

The reason why I'm asking is that I have the following in an RSpec file:

```
let (:contact) do
  contact = create(:contact)
  contact.addresses << create(:address)
  contact
end
```

As said, this works with `validates :project, :presence => true`, but it doesn't without any validation or with `validates :project_id, :presence => true`.

I could write it like this, so it works with `validates :project_id, :presence => true`, but it's just not how I guess it should behave (and it's not really DRY).

```
let (:contact) do
  contact = create(:contact)
  contact.addresses << create(:address, :contact => contact)
  contact
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In a situation like this I would always create the address by association, i.e.

```
c.addresses.create
```

So what happens when you do this, with your validation on contact_id?

Comment: This works as expected, but I really would like to find out why my code behaves like it does, as I suspect this maybe being a bug or something, or, if it's not, what's the explanation for it.