# How to perform validation on associated attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I tried to validate associated attribute `access_module_id` in `role`
 model but it doesn't work. How to give validation of `presence: true` to other model's attribute in `role` form? Here is associations

**role.rb**

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  ....
  has_many :access_module_roles, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :access_modules, through: :access_module_roles

  validates :name,:access_module_id, presence: true  # I want to validate presence of access_module_ids in role form

end
```

**access_module.rb**

```
class AccessModule < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :access_module_roles
  has_many :roles, through: :access_module_roles
end
```

**access_module_roles.rb**

```
class AccessModuleRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :access_module
  belongs_to :role

end
```

### Update

I have tried below validation and if I select one, two or all still getting an error like 
"Access module ids can't be blank"

```
  validates_presence_of :access_module_ids
```

**Controller**

```
def create
    @role = Role.new(role_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @role.save
        params[:role][:access_module_ids].each do |acmi|
          AccessModuleRole.create!(:role_id => @role.id, :access_module_id => acmi) if acmi!=""
        end
        format.html { redirect_to roles_path, notice: 'Role was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :index, status: :created, location: @role }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @role.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: this may helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689888/rails-validate-presence-of-association

Comment: another helpful link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327390/the-perfect-way-to-validate-and-test-rails-3-associations-using-rspec-remarkabl

Comment: where is your polymorphic model??

Comment: @RAJ... these three model's associations

Comment: @devanand : check my posted answer.. still getting error

Comment: @Gagan any of your model doesn't seems polymorphic.. I am updating ques title.. As per your model structure, it seems you should have `has_and_belongs_to_many`

Answer (score 0):

I found that I am doing mistake in `Create` method. I was inserting data to `AccessModuleRole` after doing save so it gets validation error while creating..And was getting parameter as `nil`

Corrected code:

```
def create
    @role = Role.new(role_params)
    @role.access_module_ids = params[:role][:access_module_ids]

    respond_to do |format|
      if @role.save
        format.html { redirect_to roles_path, notice: 'Role was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :index, status: :created, location: @role }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @role.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Permitted Role's attributes:

```
private
 def role_params
      params.require(:role).permit(:name,:chk_ids ,:description, :code, :is_active, :access_module_ids)
 end
```

Now it works perfectly.. Thanks to RAJ to pointing me :)

Comment: Anyways this is not answer, this is issue. You may edit your question and add it over there. Also how you are populating `access_module_ids`? like from input form or by using associations etc

Comment: are u getting this value in params? can you check it?

Comment: @RAJ... : Thanks Now I have solved the issue and answer is updated

Comment: I think you should not need `@role.access_module_ids = params[:role][:access_module_ids]` as this value must be already in `role_params`. So you don't need to re-assign.

Comment: If I removed that line then again getting error that's y I have put

Comment: Did you permitted `access_module_ids` in your `role_params`?